# How to use the PCF8574 i2c LCD44780 backpack with adafruit_LCD python code as gpio extender on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, i2c, hd44780

The adafruit library offers LCD control with python on RPI GPIO or over MCP230XX i2C gpio expander. I want to use the same idea for the PCF8574.
It's all about these things:
http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-iic-i2c-twi-serial-2004-20x4-lcd-module-shield-for-arduino-uno-mega-r3.html

The Adafruit library i use for the LCD is this one:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD

In Adafruit_GPIO is also contained a library for the PCF8574 i2C gpio expander.
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO

In the examples there is only made use of the MCP230XX but not of the PCF8574.

After hours of trying, i do not get that thing to work properly with the adafruit code.

Notice that i found a working code but want to use the adafruit code instead for better maintenance and support.
The working code is this one:
https://github.com/goshkis/rpi/blob/master/lcddriver.py

Here is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
import Adafruit_GPIO.PCF8574 as PCF

# Define PCF pins connected to the LCD.
PCF8574T_addr = 0x27
lcd_rs        = 0
lcd_rw        = 1
lcd_en        = 2
lcd_d4        = 4
lcd_d5        = 5
lcd_d6        = 6
lcd_d7        = 7
lcd_backlight = 3

# Define LCD column and row size for 16x2 LCD.
lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows    = 2

# Initialize i2C device using its I2C address.
gpio = PCF.PCF8574(PCF8574T_addr, busnum=1)

# Initialize the LCD
lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7,
                           lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight, gpio=gpio)

# Clear display and show greeting, pause 1 sec
lcd.clear()
lcd.set_backlight(True)
lcd.message("Gartenwasser startet...")
time.sleep(1)
```

Can you find that error i make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fork of that Adafruit repository on github shows how it works:
https://github.com/sylvandb/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD

working example:

```
import PCF_CharLCD as LCD
lcd = LCD.PCF_CharLCD(0, address=0x27, busnum=1, cols=16, lines=2)
```

Comment: The "lines" parameter is "rows" in the fork but "lines" in the original Adafruit CharLCD which i use. If you want to use the CharLCD from the fork, use "rows" instead.